# Programmatically update the value of the Flight Plan 'rotation' parameter

Tags: dronedeploy

I would like to programmatically update the value of the Flight Plan 'rotation' parameter (flight direction).
However, it seems that this parameter is part of the 'info' substructure that is read-only and cannot be updated.
Is there another way to update the rotation value? 
Obviously, I expect the flight duration to get recalculated and updated accordingly by the DroneDeploy App as a result of this update.

Comment: Hi @Eyal, DroneDeploy doesn't currently support changing the rotation via an app. However, it wouldn't be too difficult for us to add! What is your usecase?

Comment: I am thinking about flight plan optimization. Controlling the direction of the flight can be used to minimize the flight duration; other possibilities are minimizing the effects of side wind or sun glare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  @Eyal.

I think we should make that parameter available for you to edit, but bear in mind that we are intending to auto optimise the flight direction ourselves as a default feature in the next 4 weeks.

The optimisation will be relatively naive though, and only seek to reduce the flight time.